# in plotly, how to change colors with css variables?

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter-lab, plotly-python, plotly.js

I would like to be able to change colors with css variables so that when other parts of my React code changes that css variable dynamically, it should reflect the change inside of plotly frame as well. (It's jupyterlab app, so some widgets are React and some are python plotly) How can I achieve something like this? Thanks

```py
# for example it would be great if the following code would work
fig.add_annotation(
    bgcolor="var(--custom-color-var-that-dynamically-changes)",
)
```